# Nomenclature tag synonyms: naming, name, or names

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

Often newcomers ask a question dealing with naming of chemical compounds. But they might not know, that *naming* is technically called *nomenclature*. Therefore I think it would be helpful to add [naming](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) and/or [name](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/name) and/or [names](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/names) synonym(s) for [nomenclature](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nomenclature) tag.

Related with [Should we do away with the 'naming' tag?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263/should-we-do-away-with-the-naming-tag)

Comment: A reasonable recommendation, though there are currently no questions tagged with any of those three alternatives on the site right now. It may or may not serve much practical benefit. Will be curious to hear others' opinions.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what an asker considers to be "naming" might sometimes more properly fall under "terminology" instead of "nomenclature", e.g. "what is the name of this reaction?" The post you linked to already actually brought up that point.

Answer (score 5):

The post you have linked to is already almost four years old, and it was written in the early stages of our site, where the tags have been very fluid. The moderators at the time decided that merging and synonymising would be the way to go, but Richard was a bit faster cleaning out the existing tag, therefore I guess this never happend. In the last two years (where I monitored the creation of new tags) I cannot remember the tag (or variations thereof) popping up again.

Many of the nomenclature questions suffer from worse problems than not using the appropriate tag and have to be edited either way. (See the discussion about [the iupac tag](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3173/4945).)

I am not opposed to creating this synonym, but I think it is not necessary, and I also don't really see the benefit.